# Find $N$, if $a,b,c,x<1$ using the following equation $a (1-x)^N + b x^N \geq cx$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $N$, if $a$,$b$,$c$,$x$ <1 using the following equation $a (1-x)^N + b x^N \geq cx$.

I have tried to use $ln(a+b)\leq \ln(a)+\ln(b)$, but the condition that $a+b \le ab$ had not met.

Comment: By "find $N$", do you mean to find bounds on $N$ for which that statement is true? Or just any such $N$?

Comment: This is not Linear Algebra at all. What course is your problem from? If we knew that, we would have some idea as to what sort of techniques are expected.

Comment: Yes, bound on $N$ is required.

Comment: I don't know about the math field the problem belongs to because it is not a course-related problem.